# where i code Huawei In-app purchase on android studio and how i link my app with IAP

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-iap

this app secren for payment:

[image]

I want to pair these buttons with Huawei iap

- huawei iap code : https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSInAppPurchase/index.html#6
  -i watched many videos i tried but it doesn't work somtimes i dont find anything related or explanation doesn't get me to the point so please help me if u can and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple offerings in the PMS. According to the buttons you give, you can create offerings with the same price in the PMS. 0.99$,1.99$,2.99$,4.99$ Four items.

If your offering is a consumable offering (that is, the offering can be purchased multiple times after being used), you can create a consumable offering. After purchasing the consumable offering, you need to invoke the consumption [interface](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/redelivering-consumables-0000001051356573).
That way, you can continue to purchase the item next time.

Answer (score 0):

Huawei developer guide has very detailed info. to guide you through how to use HMS IAP to set up purchases for consumables. Please refer to: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/purchase-subscription-process-0000001050130250#section1328194682617

Also here is an example of HMS IAP kit usage for consumables: https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0201235405819660101?fid=0101187876626530001